# Why do turtles and snakes love my marble brick house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I've been trying recently the Minecraft mod pack Technic using the Technic launcher. It's set to "always use recommended builds".

After spending an extended stay underground oogling all the shiny new gemstones and such, I came back up to the surface and did what any minecrafter would do. I built a floating marble brick house over the ocean.

All was fine and dandy until I went to collect some sugar cane. I came back to find my house contained a pack of about six turtles! Considering I had left my front door open, I gave them the benefit of the doubt... and shoved them out a hole in the wall into the ocean below. (Turtles can swim, right?)

After making sure to close my doors this time, I went back out to harvest some rubber. After breaking my treetap and returning, I found my work area filled by several snakes! Unacceptable! I built myself a sword and now am the owner of a few snake eggs.

Why does this keep happening? **Why do I find various wildlife creatures to have spawned inside my home?**

My house is well lit by torches, if that matters. I also play on peaceful 'cause caves noises scare me quite enough, let alone creepers.

Comment: It's worth noting that most peaceful creatures *require* light to spawn, so setting up torches is only helping them spawn, not hindering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the spawning algorithm. On the ocean, there are significantly less areas suitable for spawning. When you build a house over/on the ocean, you provide a large suitable area for them to spawn in, and because it is the only one in the area, everything that would normally be spread out around there instead spawns inside your house.

Comment: incidentally its a great way to make a mob generator by making sure its ocean in all directions except for your platform

Comment: Egads... Is there any way at all to prevent this? Short of moving my house, of course.

Comment: @Aeo - Er... I think if you make the floor half slabs, they can't spawn on it. That's how it used to be, but that may have changed. Edit: Doesn't sound like it's changed.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Was fixed in 1.3, but since Technic is 1.2.5 (for now at least) that should work.

Comment: @MatthewScharley - Are you sure? I know they can now spawn on half slabs which are in the top half of the block, and double slabs, but I'm pretty sure they still can't spawn on half slabs in the bottom half of the block.

Comment: @SaintWacko: I'm 90% sure I saw it in changelogs, but I could be mistaken, I'm still playing on 1.2.5 for the sake of mods myself.

Comment: @MatthewScharley - If I weren't at work, I'd do some quick testing.